# Loop through items in "Bar styles", reading items

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

I'm basically interested in checking if the user is showing any baselines in his active view, and if yes, which one.
If for instance "Baseline1 Start" is used in Bar Styles for the active view, I'd find the matching item number.

If I were able to loop through each bar style item, such as the built-in list MS Project shows lists under "Bar styles", that would solve my problem.

I've tried using the GanttBarEditEx method, but as the documentation explains, it only returns boolean.

If I for instance want to delete an item, this code will do:

```
GanttBarStyleDelete Item:="41"
```

My problem is that I don't know what Item I'm looking for. I don't know how to read data about Item:= "41"

This code is not working, but illustrates what I want:

```
For i = 1 to 200
  if GanttBarEditEx(item:=i, from:"Baseline1 start") = True Then MsgBox i
Next
```

I'm able to figure out the item count using the same logic, when item = i returns an error, that means there's no such item and I have found max. That's how far I've gotten.

There's also a code for GanttBarStyleBaseline which could be of help!
If it's impossible to list the items, I might be able to write a code that's sets each baseline to false, then check if a change was made to the active view, and hence find the active shown baseline...Help?

Update: I noticed that `BarBoxStyles` opens the "Bar styles" window. But I'm guessing that can't be turned into a collection for looping.

Comment: I don't know MS Project that well, but there should be a `Collection` of these Object around, maybe as member of a Page/View. With this you can use a `FOR ... EACH` Loop.

Comment: I agree, a collection is needed. But after setting "activeproject" as Variant and scrolling through all the stored info in the Locals window, I can't seem to find a matching collection which stores the information I'm looking for. The closest I am (I think) is in the ViewsSingle collection. But haven't been able to figure it out yet

Comment: Yes, the API is lacking in MS Project. As you've discovered, the bar styles can be edited but not interrogated.